# How to send and listen to data via unix sockets in rust?

Tags: rust

I am trying to use unix sockets to communicate between node.js and rust. I'd like to both listen to and send messages via the rust script, however literally every example I've found on the internet is showing how to do one (either listen or send) or uses a 3rd party tool.

I am trying to send a message to the client as soon as it connects, however it is not doing that. (it stops after the  "Got a client" message)

```
use std::os::unix::net::{UnixStream,UnixListener};
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let listener = UnixListener::bind("/tmp/rst.sock")?;

    match listener.accept() {
        Ok((socket, addr)) => {
            let mut stream = UnixStream::connect("/tmp/rst.sock")?;
            println!("Got a client: {:?} - {:?}", socket, addr);
            stream.write_all(b"hello world")?;
            let mut response = String::new();
            stream.read_to_string(&mut response)?;
            println!("{}", response);
        },
        Err(e) => println!("accept function failed: {:?}", e),
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `UnixStream::connect`, you're trying to open a second connection that loops from your rust code to itself but that second connection is never accepted because your code only accepts once and it has already accepted the connection from Node.

Instead you should use the socket returned by `accept` directly:

```
use std::os::unix::net::UnixListener;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let listener = UnixListener::bind("/tmp/rst.sock")?;

    match listener.accept() {
        Ok((mut socket, addr)) => {
            println!("Got a client: {:?} - {:?}", socket, addr);
            socket.write_all(b"hello world")?;
            let mut response = String::new();
            socket.read_to_string(&mut response)?;
            println!("{}", response);
        },
        Err(e) => println!("accept function failed: {:?}", e),
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: hi, thank you! I've edited the code since the compiler was crying about socket being inmutable